# How do I get a list of friends who clicked "Like" on an external page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

**PART A** -
There are many many questions like this, but none of them seem to provide a working solution. I want to get a list of friends who clicked the Facebook "Like" button on an external site.

NOTE: This is NOT for a Facebook page. In this case, I know I can query the `page_fan` table.

To get the list of Facebook page-likes for example, I can use the `url_like` table. I guess I just want a way to invert this table. I know I cannot get a list of ALL people that liked a link due to privacy concerns, but I want a list of my friends alone - which should be fine.

I know facebook does this internally every time I see a Facebook Like button... right below that there is statistics about my friends that also like the same link. How do I get this using FQL?

**PART B** 
Equivalently, how do I get a list of friends that ***shared*** a specific URL as a link? I cannot search the `link` table by url because that is not indexed. Also, the `link_id` is not the same as the Open Graph ID of the URL.

I tried `select link_id from link where url="http://urladdress.com/a/b.html" and owner in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())`  but that neither throws an error not returns anything... just stalls.

Answer (score 0):

Part A: you can't.

Part B: you can't the way you are trying.  You **might** be able to get the feed for every one of the users friends and look for that url from their feed, but it will be painfully slow.

Lots of people would like to know this but Facebook is (rightfully so) not giving this information out.  That is why you see lots of questions regarding it but no working solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly look into the [read_insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) permission.  You might not be able to get the exact information about "likes" (yet)... but you **will** be able to get other possibly useful information.